# Derive a recursion formula for integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, recursion

Let $$I_n=\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^ndx.$$Use integration by parts to derive a recursion relation for the integral. After I used integration by parts the answer I got was
$$\left.x(1-x^2)^n\rule{0mm}{6mm}\right|_{-1}^1+2n\int_{-1}^1x^2(1-x^2)^ndx$$
After this though I don't understand what to do next.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314602/derive-recursion-formula-for-an-integral?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x^2(1-x^2)^n=(1-x^2)^n-(1-x^2)^{n+1}$.

Comment: I understand how to get the answer using that equality but how does $x^2(1-x^2)^n=(1-x^2)^n-(1-x^2)^{n+1}$?

Comment: @svarg Multiply $x^2=1-(1-x^2)$ by $(1-x^2)^n$.